# RPi OverlayFS and read-only also turns external mounted drive read-only/root-only

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mount, readonly, overlayfs

### Background

I have recently discovered and experimenting with `OverlayFS` setting in `raspi-config` on RPi3 with `openmediavault`. I am trying `OverlayFS` because system on sdcard is way too fragile. So far, this feature is able to prevent sdcard from failing.

### Issue

The external HDD mounted seems to be "read-only" after the activation of `OverlayFS`. More accurately, the external drive is root-only where it is writable with `sudo` or under `sudo su`. This is rather inconvenient since this system is configured as media hub and it doesn't make sense to use super user access for everything.

All the directories and files in the drive seems to be in `drwxr-xr-x` and `root` as owner and group (I didn't pay attention if it is the same case when OverlayFS is activated)

### Progress and Attempts

- I tried adding `rw` in `/etc/fstab` and `mount -a` to remount. But it is still unwritable to others.
- `sudo chmod +w` executes but no effect is taken.
- `sudo chown pi:pi` results in `Operation not permitted`
- modify `/etc/fstab` to include `rw,nofail`, drive is still about to root-only access.

### Questions

I am still learning the nature of `OverlayFS` + `read-only` setting and I have the following questions:

1. Is it because of `OverlayFS` + `read-only` setting that external drive is mounted with root-only access?
2. Is it possible to use `OverlayFS` + `read-only` with writeable external drive?
3. If that's not possible, any other trick to protect sdcard while writable to external drive?

Any suggestion is appreciated ~

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about software development. You might want to ask this over on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com or possibly https://unix.stackexchange.com.